# Difference between 「で」助詞 and 「だ」助動詞の連用形「で」

Tags: grammar, particle-で

Could you please explain me what exactly is the で in the following sentences and how can we distinguish 「で」助詞 and 「だ」助動詞の連用形「で」?

> 確かここの一番偉い人にあたる、荒川千歳さんだったかな。階級は一等・・・・・・何とか。忘れた。その人のところに行って、お世話になるにあたっての諸注意を受ける必要があるとのこと**で**。つい最近まで通っていた学校なのに、説明が必要なんて。な～んか、・・・・・・ - So, we should go to her office and listen to her explanation concerning our living there.

and

> これは非公開の話ということ**で**。 - This is not for the record.

Answer (score 1):

You can regard it as either 連用形 of copula or a conjunction particle, either way, it indicates the clause （…必要があるとのこと）is not the final predicate of the sentence.

To distinguish it from case particle で, testing if であって can work will help.

これは非公開の話ということで おねがいします： case particle で

これは非公開の話ということで（あって） 他人に話すべきではない: conjunction particle で